# Shorthand for NSString's stringWithFormat similar to @[], @{}, @() for NSArrays, NSDictionaries and NSNumbers?

Tags: objective-c, macros, nsstring

My question comes in two parts:

1. Is there a shorthand for creating NSStrings via stringWithFormat: similar to the shorthands for creating arrays, dictionaries and numbers as mentioned in the title. Something along the lines of:

`NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSString *foobar = @<@"foo %@", bar>`

2. If not, is it possible to create these shorthands and if so, how?

I use the stringWithFormat method quite a lot throughout my projects, and I think this would be very useful for both code simplicity and neatness.

Comment: My apologies, the title should read "shorthand" not "short and".

Comment: The term you are looking for is "object literals" (as in "string literals", "array literals", etc.)

Comment: I was using the mobile app to ask the question and couldn't seem to find the edit functionality. Thank you for the clarification David.

Answer (score 6):

No such shorthand exist but you can create a helper function

```
static inline NSString *CreateStr(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];

    va_end(ap);
    return message;
}
```

---

Use like

```
NSString *bar = @"bar";
NSString *foobar = CreateStr(@"foo %@", bar);
```

Comment: Clang would be a much better approach. `#define ss NSString stringWithFormat:`, use like: `[ss @"foo %@", bar];`